# SQL Server 2012 to php - encoding

Tags: sql-server, encoding

I have a small problem. I use SQL Server 2012 database with my small web aplication. I'm from czech republic, so i need to use unicode character stored in db..

I have one table with collate Czech_100_CI_AI. And i have in it characters like áéčř.. string columns are nvarchar

I'm using odbc driver to connect db in php..

I have problem with enconding, specifically with character with ˇ like čřšě.. It doesn't show in my page..

I'm using php function to encode the string to utf8, because sql server can't use utf8..

```
iconv("Windows-1250", "UTF-8", $val['text'])
```

This solution isn't working on characters like čšřšč but work on áíé..

Does somebody solving similar problem? Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. If you are using odbc drivers, you need to set code page to server. If the server have some code page which has not have characters like čššř, the odbc driver translate it wrong.